# Why is this class considered final?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I am trying to inherit the following type, but the compiler says it is final.

```
class Dice(private var side : Int)
{
    constructor(D : DiceTypesK) : this(D.value) {}
}

class ExplodedDice(private val D : DiceTypesK) : Dice(D) 
                                              // ^^^^ this class is final and
                                              //      can not be inherited from
```

Why my type is final, because I did not intend it to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java and C#, all classes are final by default, unless marked as `open` explicitly. Here's what's in [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance):

> The `open` annotation on a class is the opposite of Java’s `final`: it allows others to inherit from this class. By default, all classes in Kotlin are final, which corresponds to [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html), Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it.

The solution is just to mark your class as `open class Dice`.

Also, note the [limitations on `data` classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921740/2196460) inheritance: they can neither be `open` nor extend another class.